# how to get item filter by id with regex?

Tags: regex

I have a text

```
{
"item":
{
  id = 1,
  something
  value="value1"
  something
}
"item":
{
  value="value2"
  something
  id = 2,
  something
}
"item":
{
  id = 3,
  something
  value="value3"
  something
}
}
```

I want to get value by id

I had try

```
(value=.*)[\w\W]*?id = 2
```

but it get value="value1"

https://regex101.com/r/xraGIQ/1

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: How about https://regex101.com/r/xraGIQ/2

Comment: I use python3 re

Comment: This problem has troubled me all day, thank you very much for your answer.exactly the answer I want.

Comment: So you only wanted the value when id=2 not id=1 or 3?  Because if you wanted it for any id the accepted answer doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(?:(id = \d+)[^{}]*?(value="[^"\r\n]*")|(value="[^"\r\n]*")[^{}]*?(id = \d+))`

will match all pairs id/value

**Explanation:**

```
(?:
    (id = \d+)              # group 1, id
    [^{}]*?                 # 0 or more any character but curly braces
    (value="[^"\r\n]*")     # group 2, value
  |                         # OR
    (value="[^"\r\n]*")     # group 3, value
    [^{}]*?                 # 0 or more any character but curly braces
    (id = \d+)              # group 4, id
)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YWooji/4)

Comment: @dopstar: Thanks you, fixed. I don't know what happened, it was working few minutes ago.

Comment: i think you should include the braces in your negative lookahead to at least avoid this: https://regex101.com/r/YWooji/2